# How can I print a conversation on Samsung S7?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s7, printing

I need to print a conversation that contains over 200 messages, can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

[Print Text Messages](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.create.solutions.printtextmessagesfree) is useful if you need to print SMS messages for legal or business reasons.Using this you can print or save as pdf. App contain two options, Quick Print and Advanced Print.

Quick Print : select a conversation and print all messages in it.

Advanced Print : Based on a date range.

[Source](http://www.printtextmessages.net/)